# Сделать разный description для разных страниц сайта

Tags: wordpress, seo, header

Как сделать разное описание в `<meta name="description" content="..." />` для разных страниц сайта на Wordpress? Для главной и для страниц статей. Для категорий и тегов не надо.
С помощью какого php кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользуйтесь wordpress-функциями `is_front_page()`, `is_single()`, `is_home()` для того, чтобы определить, на какой странице находитесь. В зависимости от результата их выполнения выводите соответствующий контент в мета-теге.

Например, уникальное описание для статей можно задавать так:

1. При создании/редактировании статьи задавайте описание в поле "цитата" (если вы его не видите - смотрите в правый верхний угол, нажимаете "настройки экрана", ставите галку рядом с полем "цитата")

[image: введите описание в поле "цитата"]

2. и далее в коде

   `<?php if (is_single()){ ?>
   <meta name="description" content="<?php the_excerpt(); ?>" />
   <?php } ?>`

Comment: это да, а если мне надо для конкретной статьи из блога задать определённый description, например для урла mysite.net/blog/article-1 свой description, для mysite.net/blog/article-2 другой...

Comment: возможно is_single('mysite.net/blog/article-1');

Comment: но так не получается..всё равно один и тот же description выдаёт

Comment: Обновила ответ.

Comment: Отлично! Теперь всё получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте плагин (Yoast Seo)[https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/]. Он позволяет задавать кастомные дескрипшены и тайтлы для статей и не только.